# Total Market Cap Data Set

Tags: currencies, technical-analysis

I want to get the data for the total market cap similar to what I see when I view this page in the total market capitalization graph.

https://coinmarketcap.com/charts/

I already have the bitcoin market cap data but are there any publicly available datasets or is there anyway to get it directly from coinmarketcap? I'd like to be able to get as much data as I can.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.coingecko.com/en also has some dataset you can collect
Like example for a coin https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/bitcoin
you can use the export as excel or csv to get some data

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried CMC's REST API? https://coinmarketcap.com/api/